# TFS 2012 Build service does not bind

Tags: build, web-config

I would like to ask for a little help.
I have a newly installed TFS server, and I can't get the Build service running.
The TFS and the Build server is on the same network, but 2 different virtual machines.
The build server could register the controller and the build aent to the TFS server, so there is no "connectivity" issue.

- After I queue the Build I get the "Running for 0 seconds" message that stays there until I cancel it or restart the Build service
- On the build server I see that the Controller and the Agent is 'Ready" but there is a  red recangle next to them.

I searched the interwebz and found that this problem usually appears when there are multiple bindings to the TFS server, but mine has only one. (SSL tough)

---

Details:

- TFS 2012 update 2
- 1 IIS bind: h__ps://tfs2012.company.hu:8080/tfs (yes, not the default SSL port)
- Everyone is on Win2012
- Bindings:
  port 80 Sharepoint
  port 80 Reporting server   (/Reports Virtual Directory)
  port 443 Sharepoint (SSL)
  port 8080 TFS       (SSL)
- Error log from the Build server:

> Build machine opv-builder lost connectivity to message queue tfsmq://buildservicehost-1004/.
>      Reason: Please contact your administrator. There was an error contacting the server.
>      Technical information (for administrator):
>      HTTP code 500: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException

- Picture of the Bindings that TFS has: http://13i.imghost.us/GI/bind.jpg
- The Message queue web.config file:

> ```
>   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
>     <configuration>
>      <system.serviceModel>
>    <protocolMapping>
>      <remove scheme="http" />
>      <add scheme="http" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="TfsSoapBinding"/>
>      <add scheme="https" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="TfsSoapBindingHttps"/>
>    </protocolMapping> 
>    <bindings>
>      <customBinding>
>        <binding name="TfsSoapBinding">
>          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10" />
>          <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Ntlm" manualAddressing="true" />
>        </binding>
>      </customBinding>
>    </bindings>
>    <behaviors> 
>      <serviceBehaviors> 
>        <behavior name="LongPollingThrottleBehavior">
>          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="5000" /> 
>        </behavior>
>      </serviceBehaviors> 
>    </behaviors>
>    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"     multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
>    <services>
>      <service name="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Core.WebServices.MessageQueueWebService"
>        behaviorConfiguration="LongPollingThrottleBehavior" />
>      <service name="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Core.WebServices.MessageQueueWebService2"
>        behaviorConfiguration="LongPollingThrottleBehavior" />
>    </services>
>  </system.serviceModel>
> ```
>
> I guess that the problem is that there is no normal http binding. But I have no experinece in editing the web.config files, don't know their structure, so I am helpless on what to even google.

- NTLM authentication?
- Windows Integrated authentication?

Comment: Actually this will remain unanwsered, as I reinstalled the TFS infrastructure all together, and the problem did not come foward again. IT works in misterios ways...

Answer (score 0):

Check the memory utilization on the machine that hosts your TFS repository.  We get symptoms that match your problem whenever it breaches 95%.  Had to tech SQL Server to share, and then it was all good.

I wish I could tell you why.

Answer (score 0):

Though this issue has gone away for you, I had the same issue so I'll post my findings here for anyone else who encounters it.

> The build server could register the controller and the build sent to the TFS server, so there is no "connectivity" issue.

Just because you were able to register your agent with the server doesn't mean it will be able to connect to it during a build.

> ...but there is a red recangle next to them.

I'll assume you're referring to the red stop sign in the build machine's TFS build administration console. At one point, my main purpose in life was to get that icon to be the green triangle of build happiness. The elation I experienced when that happened was proportionate with how long it will took me to accomplish that, and was, as such, after several days of trying great enough to cause me to yell out. My goal is, unfortunately, to minimize that elation for you. Here's how I did it:

For me that red icon was caused by an issue of network connectivity, so I'll start with how to resolve that. When following these steps, as soon as the green icon emerges, use standard debugging techniques to go back and undo your changes one-by-one until you've isolated the cause. BTW, I follow these steps for most network connectivity issues, and they have served me well.

- Can your TFS server ping your build machine? Can your build machine ping the TFS server? If not, then get them to do that.
- Start by disabling the Windows firewall entirely for all networks on both VMware client machines. If they're running on different VMware ESX/server hosts, then disable the Windows firewalls on both hosts, as well. You're no doubt protected by a corporate firewall from the Internet, and we'll close this later.
- With your machines on a domain, they may be subject to a group policy that will re-enable the firewall automatically and silently. This is what happened to me. To inhibit this for the time being, stop and disable the "Windows Firewall/ICS" Service on all of the above listed machines. Creating a firewall exception for TCP port 9191 does not suffice. Maybe UDP would work, but for me TFS build got a red stop sign if I don't do this.
- Check that both guests network adapters are running in "Bridged" mode. Again, we can revert to NAT if this fixes things, but we want to rule this out for now. You don't want to add extra complexities to your network debugging for the moment, however.
- Run IPConfig on both VMware client machines. Get and compare the IP addresses of each. Do they both start with the same 3 numbers and only differ in the 4th number (the number after the last dot)? If not, then they're on different subnets and thus can't "see" each other. In that case, you need to move one to be on the same subnet as the other.
- Open the network properties for the active network connection. If on both machines they are set to automatically get an IP address and a gateway, then they should be on the same subnet. Ask your IT department for help here.
- I won't go into the details of the VMware virtual network editor (in VMware Workstation) or similar tool in ESX, but if you're running both machines on the same host using host-only networking, then you'll need to familiarize yourself with how this works.

To understand more about VMware host networks and how to configure them to network connect multiple guests, see [this network diagram](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_custom.html) and [these smaller diagrams](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_common.html) showing how Bridged, NAT, and host-only network options fit into it.

I'll just assume that they aren't talking over a VPN. If they are, then the following could be the issue:
   - They may have a corporate firewall interfering.

- If the VMware host is connected to the corporate Intranet via a VPN, then the guest can be connected in “NAT” or in “Bridged” mode as long as the VPN software is being run directly on the guest (not on the host). Otherwise the DHCP thinks it’s issuing two IP addresses, and the guest gets none.
- If the VMware host is connected to the corporate Intranet via a direct cable (not VPN), then the client may be required to be connected in “Bridged” mode, not in NAT mode. That was an issue for our machine, and was likely due to one IT network policy or another.
- If your build machine is connected to the network wirelessly (I'm just saying), then connect it with a wire for now during testing.